# Perform calculations in every file in the path with loop?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a code that finds every file in the directory with a certain extension:

and i want this script to be applied to every shp:

```
import geopandas as gpd
pst = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder1\PST')#this is not needed in the final because it takes the path by it self
dbound = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder1\DBOUND')#same here
dbound.reset_index(inplace=True)
dbound = dbound.rename(columns={'index': 'fid'})
wdp = gpd.sjoin(pst, dbound, how="inner", op='within')#each dbound and pst from every subfolder
wdp['DEC_ID']=wdp['fid']
```

this is the  list that contains the paths to the shapefiles:

`grouped_shapefiles` that has these shapefiles:

```
[['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20194\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20194\\PST\\PST.shp'],
 ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20042\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20042\\PST\\PST.shp'],
 ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20161\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20161\\PST\\PST.shp'],
 ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20029\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20029\\PST\\PST.shp'],
 ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20008\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20008\\PST\\PST.shp']]
```

and i want something like this:

```
results = []
for group in grouped_shapefiles:

#here applies the script where i need help to connect in the loop
#and then the export process- the line that follows
#o=a path
out = o +'\result.shp'#here it would be nice to add to the name in the output the name of its folder so it would be unique 
data2.to_file(out)
```

How can i do that?

Comment: I dont think I understand what you problem is. Why dont you just substitute group where the files are opened and processed ?